# python3-pip installed, but returns "command not found"?

Tags: python, pip, raspberry-pi2

There are a few other posts I've found that address my question but none of them solve my problem so I'm creating this post.

I'm trying to install rpi.gpio for my Raspberry Pi B+.  I installed python3-pip, but every time I try to call it from the command line with pip3 I get "command not found".  I uninstalled it with:

```
sudo apt-get remove python3-pip
```

then reinstalled

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

and got the following:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python3-pip
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 183 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/79.7 kB of archives.
After this operation, 361 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package python3-pip.
(Reading database ... 70831 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking python3-pip (from .../python3-pip_1.1-3_all.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up python3-pip (1.1-3) ...
```

But when I try to do:

```
sudo pip3 install rpi.gpio
```

I get:

```
sudo: pip3: command not found
```

I've tried suggestions from this site and others to see if pip is installed and where to locate it, but I always get "command not found":

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ locate pip3
bash: locate: command not found
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ pip --version
bash: pip: command not found
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ python3-pip --version
bash: python3-pip: command not found
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ python3.2-pip --version
bash: python3.2-pip: command not found
```

How can I get pip to install???  This is driving me nuts....

Comment: are you running Raspian (wheezy or jessie) or ubuntu (which version)?

Comment: sorry I meant to include that: Raspbian wheezy

Comment: This might be better suited for [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) to find the command used to list the contents of the `python3-pip` package.

Comment: possibly https://superuser.com/questions/769920/python3-pip-installed-but-pip3-command-not-found helps...

Comment: As a closing note to anyone reading this in the future, there were other problems I was experiencing besides the one described here.  I later decided to just start over with jessie and every problem I was experiencing including this one went away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To install `locate` run

```
sudo apt-get install mlocate
```

Then update the locatedb with

```
sudo updatedb
```

This could take sometime depending on the number of files you have on your machine

locate should work now and show you where all the pip's are

Back to the root problem.
In Raspian wheezy, pip is managed with `pip-3.2`, you can easily create a `pip3` alias or a symlink to it to avoid typing `pip-3.2` every time.

```
pip-3.2 install rpi.gpio
```

For more info you can read the [docs](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/software/python.md) on python packages and raspberry pi

Comment: Oh wow that fixed everything.  Thanks so much!  I'm not well versed in linux and I just thought `locate` was a standard shell command.  Using pip-3.2 worked whereas pip3 did not!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use:

```
sudo python3 -m pip
```

or

```
sudo python -m pip
```

Comment: The first command returns `/usr/bin/python3: No module named pip.__main__; 'pip' is a package and cannot be directly executed`.  The second command returns `/usr/bin/python: No module named pip`

Comment: How about using get-pip.py from pip website?  [get-pip](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py)

Comment: if pip is at least installed semi-correctly these commands should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use `python3 -m pip` (possibly with `sudo`) if the library is available - like installed to the right place. This does not depend on pip being installed as a normal command which is just a shortcut for this.

Comment: Thank you, but see my reply to the other comment which suggested the same.